# Passing Data from Activity to Other [Not working]

Tags: android, android-intent

From my StartActivity class which is an Actvity, i am calling another activity using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CHANGE_PACK, changePack);
startActivity(intent);
```

CHANGE_PACK is static final String and changePack value is true. ( I have checked it by debugging)

But when i am fetching this value in TabsActivity by

```
boolean packChanged = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(StartActivity.CHANGE_PACK, false);
```

The value of packChanged is false. I checked on internet but no help found. Basically i am using exact same thing else where in my Application and it is working fine.

Anybody can tell why it is not working.

Additional: Both Activities are registered in manifest and i am doing this in onResume() method of both Activities.

Comment: changePack is also a boolean. I am putting a boolean value and trying to fetch a boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `getIntent().getBooleanExtra(...)` in onCreate instead. Or Override `protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` and retrieve your boolean from that intent object.

Answer (score 3):

Check how TabsActivity `android:launchMode` is declared in manifest.
If it's `singleTop`, or `singleTask` you should use `onNewIntent()` in your TabsActivity (instead of onResume) to get fresh extras from the new intent. getIntent in that situation will return the first, original intent used to create instance of this Activity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

P.S. Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

...

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    boolean packChanged = intent.getBooleanExtra(StartActivity.CHANGE_PACK, false);
}
```

}

Comment: its launch mode is android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: That means no new instance of your activity is created on startActivity(intent) and, therefore, getIntent will always return an old intent to you. Try overriding onNewIntent method like I suggested and get your extra boolean value there

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and wasn't able to solve it nicely. I ended up using the following hack:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CHANGE_PACK, Boolean.toString(changePack));
startActivity(intent);
```

and then

```
boolean packChanged = Boolean.parseBoolean(getIntent().getStringExtra(StartActivity.CHANGE_PACK));
```

Hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. The only place where you the way you are handling the `CHANGE_PACK` variable. Try to use it along with the class name (since its declared Static). Use  `intent.putExtra(StartActivity.CHANGE_PACK, changePack);`.

Comment: I am calling TabsActivity from StartActivity so their is no need for mentioning the class name as the variable is the same class.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
boolean packChanged;

Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extra!=null){
        packChanged=extra.getBoolean("enter your key which u have used in StartActivity");

    }
```